# Possible to automatically get size / coordinates of squares in image?

Tags: javascript, php, bash, image-processing

I was just talking to a friend last night about one of their projects and they said they had manually created an image map for a trade show using Adobe Fireworks. I was thinking of some of the code golf things I had seen in the past like this one asking how cloudy the day is: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136405/how-cloudy-is-it

Made me think that this should be able to be done automatically. Any tips on how to use PHP / Javascript to either auto create an image map, or get size / coordinates of each square where you could overlay divs over them with absolute positioning so you could click on it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**JS**:
I was not aware of this but apparent [jQuery can read image dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript).

**PHP**:
[ImageMagik can read an image and provided image dimensions](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=18625) (as well as much more info about the image. To interface with is using PHP [a number of libraries exist](https://packagist.org/?q=Imagemagick&idx=packagist&p=0) to do exactly that.

Comment: Thanks David, I have worked with ImageMagik and jQuery to do this in other projects, but what I was wondering is how to get the size and position of the Sony booth in the bottom left as an example.

Comment: @Alan , Ahm ok, For that you'll be wanting to leverage OCR (optical character recognition) and then some sort of color / pattern recognition system. Have the OCR find `Sony`, then find the encapsulating color pattern (or search for the color black. then cycle and find the co-ordinates of the corners. For OCR this looks promising https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php for the pattern / color segment. I am at a lose for that at the moment.

Comment: Found one for shapes: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/

Comment: Ah, OpenCV (computer vision); a very interesting part of computing. Thought written in python (OP title states PHP/JS). Best of luck, let us know how it turns out!